# How to prevent sites from detecting tab/window changes?

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom, browser

Basically, I want sites to not be able to detect whether or not I exit out of site (change tabs, switch to other window, etc.).
This could mean either the `visibilitystate` or permanently having the website in a `focused` state. How can I accomplish this by auto-injecting JS code upon every site load?

Google Chrome on MacOS.

Comment: You can use an extension like Tampermonkey to inject JS. I've never tried it, but you could probably just overwrite the existing handlers they've implemented to prevent them from firing.